# Create scalable Y axis with customized ticks

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I currently have a bar chart that has a bar for each school.  I've already made the X axis with numbered ticks, but now I want to add a Y Axis that labels each school next to its respective bar.

Here is an array for the schools:

```
var schoolArray = ["Berkeley", "Brown", "Caltech", "CMU", "College of William and Mary", "Columbia", "Cornell",
    "Dartmouth", "Gatech", "JHU", "MIT", "Northwestern", "NYU", "Notre Dame", "OSU", "Princeton", "PSU", "Purdue", "Rice",
    "RPI", "Rutgers", "Stanford", "U. of Chicago", "U. of Wisconsin Madison", "UCB", "UCDavis", "UCI", "UCLA", "UCR", "UCSB",
    "UCSC", "UCSD", "UF", "UIUC", "Umich", "UMN", "UNC", "Upenn", "USC", "Utah", "UTAustin", "Uva", "UW", "Vanderbilt", "WUSTL", "Yale"]
```

I've also made a value/key array:

```
var combined = [
    {"val": 17, "key": "Berkeley"}, {"val": 18, "key": "Brown"},
    {"val": 23, "key": "Caltech"}, {"val": 17, "key": "CMU"},
    {"val": 9, "key": "College of William and Mary"}, {"val": 22, "key": "Columbia"},
    {"val": 22, "key": "Cornell"}, {"val": 22, "key": "Dartmouth"},
    {"val": 16, "key": "Gatech"}, {"val": 18, "key": "JHU"},
    {"val": 14, "key": "MIT"}, {"val": 12, "key": "Northwestern"},
    {"val": 14, "key": "NYU"}, {"val": 11, "key": "Notre Dame"},
    {"val": 14, "key": "OSU"}, {"val": 15, "key": "Princeton"},
    {"val": 12, "key": "PSU"}, {"val": 17, "key": "Purdue"},
    {"val": 21, "key": "Rice"}, {"val": 14, "key": "RPI"},
    {"val": 11, "key": "Rutgers"}, {"val": 25, "key": "Stanford"},
    {"val": 13, "key": "U. of Chicago"}, {"val": 22, "key": "U. of Wisconsin Madison"},
    {"val": 16, "key": "UCB"}, {"val": 12, "key": "UCDavis"},
    {"val": 18, "key": "UCI"}, {"val": 16, "key": "UCLA"},
    {"val": 18, "key": "UCR"}, {"val": 17, "key": "UCSB"},
    {"val": 15, "key": "UCSC"}, {"val": 18, "key": "UCSD"},
    {"val": 11, "key": "UF"}, {"val": 18, "key": "UIUC"},
    {"val": 18, "key": "Umich"}, {"val": 13, "key": "UMN"},
    {"val": 10, "key": "UNC"}, {"val": 18, "key": "Upenn"},
    {"val": 23, "key": "USC"}, {"val": 15, "key": "Utah"},
    {"val": 20, "key": "UTAustin"}, {"val": 17, "key": "Uva"},
    {"val": 21, "key": "UW"}, {"val": 11, "key": "Vanderbilt"},
    {"val": 14, "key": "WUSTL"}, {"val": 17, "key": "Yale"}
    ]
```

Here is the height scale, yAxis and appended to the canvas:

```
//There are 46 total schools
var heightScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, 46])
                    .range([0, height]);
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(heightScale)
              .orient("left")
              .ticks(46);
canvas.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)")
        .call(yAxis);
```

I don't know if this will be useful but here is the code related to the xAxis:

```
var widthScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, 25])
                    .range([0, width]);
var xaxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .ticks("20")
                    .scale(widthScale);
var canvas = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(50, 0)");

var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(dataArray)
                    .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("width", function(d) {return widthScale(d)})
                    .attr("height", 6)
                    .attr("fill", function(d) {return color(d)})
                    .attr("y", function(d, i) {return i * 15});

canvas.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, 690)")
        .call(xaxis);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to an [ordinal scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales) on your y-axis:

```
var heightScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, height], .1) //<-- separate bars with a padding
  .domain(schoolArray); //<-- domain is our text array of schools
```

When you use this scale later to set the y position, you need to pass in the school name that belongs to that bar, so don't use:

```
.attr("y", function(d, i) {return i * 15});
```

But rather (*note* I'm be passing in `combinded` instead of `dataarray`:

```
var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
  .data(combinded)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", function(d) {return widthScale(d.val)})
  .attr("height", heightScale.rangeBand() ) //<-- can use rangeBand here which is a computed height based on number of bars, height of graph and padding
  .attr("fill", function(d) {return color(d)})
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {return heightScale(d.key)});
```